# pie chart for each column pandas

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns, pie-chart

I have a dataframe of categorical values, and want to tabulate, then make a pie graph on each column.

I can tabulate my table and create one massive plot, but I do not think this meets my needs, and would prefer a pie graph for each column instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['table', 'chair', 'chair', 'lamp', 'bed'],
                   'b': ['lamp', 'candle', 'chair', 'lamp', 'bed'],
                   'c': ['mirror', 'mirror', 'mirror', 'mirror', 'mirror']})
df
df2=df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)
df2.plot.bar()
display()
```

[image]

I tried making pie plots for each column, but have been struggling the past few hours with:

```
df2.plot(kind='pie',subplots=True,autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=270, fontsize=17)
display()
```

[image]

I am thinking I am close, and hopefully soeone can help me get over the final hurdle. ie, make a pie graph based on each column, so that it is meaningful and interpretable, not this bungled mess (ie, a title above each plot referring to the column, the legend in an appropriate position), or even the correct documentation to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy thing to do is to increase the figure size and specify the layout:

```
df2.plot(kind='pie', subplots=True,
         autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=270, fontsize=17,
         layout=(2,2), figsize=(10,10))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: do you know how to remove the y-label, or put it as a title instead?

Comment: do you also know how to position legend in a better location, o it does not overlap a value?